# Remove comma at the end of a string

Tags: python-3.x

how to remove comma at end??in python

```
s=input()
for i in s :
print(i,end=",")
```

Output

```
sabari

s,a,b,a,r,i,
```

Comment: `print(','.join(s))`

Comment: `print(*s,sep=",")`